# How to list constant attributes of external Python library, likely a wrapped C library?

Tags: python, constants

I am working with a Python library that I do not have the source code for and which consists of compiled `*.pyd` modules. The library has attributes that appear to be constants (integers) which set various parameters in what I assume is a wrapped C-library.

For example:

```py
# pixet is the library name

pixet.PX_TPX3_OPM_TOATOT # is equal to integer 0
pixet.PX_TPX3_OPM_EVENT_ITOT # is equal to integer 2
```

Since I do not have the source or the header files, I am not sure of what all the possibilities are and they do not show up in `dir(pixet)`. Other than some kind of silly brute-force try all possible attribute names, is there a way that I can get a list of the integer constants, or are they hidden in the compiled code?

Comment: It's not listed in `pixet.__dict__`?

Comment: Indeed it is not.